# Upstart is checking and trying to start the process everytime and is taking 99% CPU

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, upstart, init.d

I have a ruby process that has to be started on the system boot. So i created the init.d file for it in the `/etc/init.d directory`. the file is `/etc/init.d/remote_syslog`

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
#       /etc/init.d/remote_syslog
#
# Starts the remote_syslog daemon
#
# chkconfig: 345 90 5
# description: Runs remote_syslog
#
# processname: remote_syslog

[[ -s "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

source "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

prog="remote_syslog"
config="/etc/log_files.yml"
pid_dir="/home/ubuntu"

EXTRAOPTIONS=""

pid_file="$pid_dir/$prog.pid"


PATH=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH

RETVAL=0

is_running(){
  [ -e $pid_file ]
}

start(){
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "

    unset HOME MAIL USER USERNAME
    $prog -c $config --pid-file $pid_file $EXTRAOPTIONS
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    return $RETVAL
}

stop(){
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    if (is_running); then
      kill `cat $pid_file`
      RETVAL=$?
      echo
      return $RETVAL
    else
      echo "$pid_file not found"
    fi
}

status(){
    echo -n $"Checking for $pid_file: "

    if (is_running); then
      echo "found"
    else
      echo "not found"
    fi
}

reload(){
    restart
}

restart(){
    stop
    start
}

condrestart(){
    is_running && restart
    return 0
}


# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
    start)
  start
  ;;
    stop)
  stop
  ;;
    status)
  status
  ;;
    restart)
  restart
  ;;
    reload)
  reload
  ;;
    condrestart)
  condrestart
  ;;
    *)
  echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|reload}"
  RETVAL=1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

It starts the process by running the following command
`/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/remote_syslog -c /etc/log_files.yml --pid-file /home/ubuntu/remote_syslog.pid`

I wrote the upstart script to make sure the process respawn

```
description "Monitor files and send to remote syslog"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]


respawn

exec sudo /etc/init.d/remote_syslog start >> /tmp/upstart.log 2>&1
```

this file is saved as '/etc/init/remote_syslog_upstart.conf'

By checking `/tmp/upstart.log`, every second, I learnt, it tries to run the ruby command by calling the init.d script and since it will be already running, the ruby command return saying `Already running at /home/ubuntu/remote_syslog.pid.`

Now, the problem is, since its executing the ruby command every time, ruby is taking up 99% of CPU and I'm able to do anything else on the system.

This is the first time I'm working with upstart. Am I doing something wrong here.?